# How to negate this filter in Django?

Tags: django, django-filter

Here is my view function:

```
def job_find(request):
    queryset = Job.objects.filter(user=request.user).order_by('created_at')
    jobs = get_list_or_404(queryset)
    return render(request, 'jobs/all_jobs.html', {'jobs': jobs})
```

I want the queryset to contain all jobs which do not belong to the current user. To do this I must negate the filter, but how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`exclude`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters):

```
queryset = Job.objects.exclude(user=request.user).order_by('created_at')
```